# How to set animation-fill-mode of in parameters of .animate function vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I am struggling to find documentation or examples of the method in *vanilla* JavaScript that allows me to set the `animation-fill-mode`. I am using the `Element.animate(animation, timing)` function to achieve this.

I have attempted adding `animation-fill-mode` to the entries of the `timing` object, but it is not a valid parameter according to my tests. I have also attempted to use `Animation.onfinish` and `Animation.pause()` in tandem to pause it when it completes, but that also does not work. Here is all the code that this uses:

```
const quotemove = [
    { transform: "translate(0vw) rotate(0deg)" },
    { transform: "translate(80vw) rotate(180deg)" }
]

const quotetiming = {
    duration: 1000,
    iterations: 1,
    // this is where i attempted to add fill mode    
}

const quoteholders = document.getElementsByClassName("quote")
for(let i = 0; i < quoteholders.length; i++) {
    let quoteholder = quoteholders.item(i)
    const quotemark = quoteholder.querySelector(".quotationmark")
    quoteholder.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        let animation = quotemark.animate(quotemove, quotetiming)
    })     
}
```

I should also mention that I intend on adding another animation to the `mouseout` event so that it stays in one position while you hover, and another when not.

If it is not possible to set the fill mode to `forwards` and in the future implement the above request, then is there another similar approach I should consider? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `quotetiming` KeyframeEffect object would be the right place.
Not sure what you did wrong, what you need is to set the `fill` property:

```js
const quotemove = [
    { transform: "translate(0vw) rotate(0deg)" },
    { transform: "translate(80vw) rotate(180deg)" }
]

const quotetiming = {
    duration: 1000,
    iterations: 1,
    fill: "forwards"
}

const quoteholders = document.getElementsByClassName("quote")
for(let i = 0; i < quoteholders.length; i++) {
    let quoteholder = quoteholders.item(i)
    const quotemark = quoteholder.querySelector(".quotationmark")
    quoteholder.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        let animation = quotemark.animate(quotemove, quotetiming)
    })     
}
```

```css
.quote {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightgray;
}
blockquote {
  background: ivory;
  transform-origin: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  <blockquote class="quotationmark">Hover the page</blockquote>
</div>
```